# Bootstrap: Container expanded for seemingly no reason

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have been working on a website using Bootstrap 3.3.1.  One of my pages has a form for registration. For some reason, this form has become extremely long, going down over 1000px to the bottom of the page. I have not changed any of the code that this page uses since I last checked when it was good.

This is what the website looks like right now.

[image]

I'm confused as to how this could have happened. Any help would be greatly appreaciated.

```css
.btn-file {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.child {
  text-align: left;
}
.margintop {
  margin-top: 10px;
}
.chart-legend li {
  display: inline;
  padding-right: 10px;
}
.chart-legend li span {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  margin-right: 2px;
}
.chart-legend > ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding-left: 0px;
}
.dropspan {
  width: 80px;
}
.modal-header-success {
  color: #fff;
  padding: 9px 15px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
  background-color: #5cb85c;
  -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius-topleft: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius-topright: 5px;
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
}
.modal-header-warning {
  color: #fff;
  padding: 9px 15px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
  background-color: #f0ad4e;
  -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius-topleft: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius-topright: 5px;
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
}
.modal-header-danger {
  color: #fff;
  padding: 9px 15px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
  background-color: #d9534f;
  -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius-topleft: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius-topright: 5px;
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
}
.modal-header-info {
  color: #fff;
  padding: 9px 15px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
  background-color: #5bc0de;
  -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius-topleft: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius-topright: 5px;
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
}
.modal-header-primary {
  color: #fff;
  padding: 9px 15px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
  background-color: #428bca;
  -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius-topleft: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius-topright: 5px;
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
}
canvas {
  margin-left: -15px;
}
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  /* The html and body elements cannot have any padding or margin. */
}
/* Wrapper for page content to push down footer */

.wrap {
  min-height: 100%;
  height: auto;
  /* Negative indent footer by its height */
  margin: 0 auto -40px;
  /* Pad bottom by footer height */
  padding: 0 0 40px;
}
/* Set the fixed height of the footer here */

#footer {
  height: 40px;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}
@media print {
  a[href]:after {
    content: none !important;
  }
  .col1 {
    display: none;
  }
}
.actionsdrop > .edit > a:hover,
.actionsdrop > .edit > a:focus {
  background-image: none !important;
  color: white;
}
.actionsdrop > .edit > a:hover,
.actionsdrop > .edit > a:focus {
  background-color: #357ebd !important;
  color: white;
}
.actionsdrop > .delete > a:hover,
.actionsdrop > .delete > a:focus {
  background-image: none !important;
  color: white;
}
.actionsdrop > .delete > a:hover,
.actionsdrop > .delete > a:focus {
  background-color: #d9534f !important;
  color: white;
}
.btn-file input[type=file] {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  font-size: 100px;
  text-align: right;
  filter: alpha(opacity=0);
  opacity: 0;
  outline: none;
  background: white;
  cursor: inherit;
  display: block;
}
.form-group.required label:after {
  content: " *";
  color: red;
}
.container {
  padding-top: 15px;
}
.status {
  color: #ffffff;
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  text-align: right;
}
.form-inline > * {
  margin: 5px 10px;
}
.inner-shadow {
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 55px -20px #000000;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 55px -20px #000000;
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 55px -20px #000000;
  -o-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 55px -20px #000000;
}
.navbar .divider-vertical {
  height: 50px;
  margin: 0 9px;
  border-right: 1px solid #ffffff;
  border-left: 1px solid #f2f2f2;
}
.navbar-inverse .divider-vertical {
  border-right-color: #222222;
  border-left-color: #111111;
}
.glyphicon.glyphicon-cog {
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 0px;
}
.glyphicon.glyphicon-inbox {
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 0px;
}
.loginerrors {
  color: #cc5f3b;
  height: auto;
  text-align: center;
}
.fullheight {
  height: 100%;
  margin: auto;
}
.blue {
  background-color: #357ebd;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .colw {
    width: 80px;
  }
  .modal-content {
    margin-top: 150px;
  }
  .mtop {
    margin-top: 60px;
  }
  .navbar .navbar-nav {
    display: inline-block;
    float: none;
    vertical-align: top;
  }
  .navbar .navbar-collapse {
    text-align: center;
  }
  .navbar-center li {
    width: 155px;
  }
  #toggle7 {
    height: 50px;
  }
  .navbar-center {
    padding-right: 90px;
  }
  .actioncol1 {
    width: 70px;
  }
  .actioncol2 {
    width: 120px;
  }
  .btn-edit,
  .btn-delete {
    width: 49px;
  }
}
.logo {
  font-size: 20px;
  padding-top: 7px;
}
#addorgtabbtn {
  padding-right: 5px;
  padding-left: 5px;
}
@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .dropspan:before {
    top: 8px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    height: 16px;
    width: 16px;
    display: block;
    color: white;
    border: 2px solid white;
    border-radius: 16px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 14px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 3px #444;
    box-sizing: content-box;
    background-color: #31b131;
    background-color: #5bc0de !important;
    left: 10px !important;
    top: 6px !important;
  }
  .smsize {
    font-size: 13px !important;
  }
  .dataTables_filter {
    font-size: 0px;
  }
  .dataTables_length {
    font-size: 0px;
  }
  .modal-content {
    margin-top: 80px;
  }
  .navbar-brand {
    text-align: center;
  }
  .logo {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    text-align: center;
    margin: auto;
  }
  #logoimg {
    display: none;
  }
  .actioncol1 {
    width: 50px;
  }
  .btn-edit,
  .btn-delete {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .hidecol {
    display: none;
  }
  #addbox {
    display: block;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
  }
  #chevr {
    display: none;
  }
  .nav-tabs li {
    width: 33%;
  }
  .brand-centered {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    text-align: center;
    margin: auto;
    height: 100%;
  }
}
.panel.with-nav-tabs .panel-heading {
  padding: 5px 5px 0 5px;
}
.panel.with-nav-tabs .nav-tabs {
  border-bottom: none;
}
.panel.with-nav-tabs .nav-justified {
  margin-bottom: -1px;
}
.with-nav-tabs.panel-default .nav-tabs > li > a,
.with-nav-tabs.panel-default .nav-tabs > li > a:hover,
.with-nav-tabs.panel-default .nav-tabs > li > a:focus {
  color: #777;
}
.with-nav-tabs.panel-default .nav-tabs > .open > a,
.with-nav-tabs.panel-default .nav-tabs > .open > a:hover,
.with-nav-tabs.panel-default .nav-tabs > .open > a:focus,
.with-nav-tabs.panel-default .nav-tabs > li > a:hover,
.with-nav-tabs.panel-default .nav-tabs > li > a:focus {
  color: #777;
  background-color: #ddd;
  border-color: transparent;
}
.with-nav-tabs.panel-default .nav-tabs > li.active > a,
.with-nav-tabs.panel-default .nav-tabs > li.active > a:hover,
.with-nav-tabs.panel-default .nav-tabs > li.active > a:focus {
  color: #555;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-color: #ddd;
  border-bottom-color: transparent;
}
.with-nav-tabs.panel-default .nav-tabs > li.dropdown .dropdown-menu {
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  border-color: #ddd;
}
.with-nav-tabs.panel-default .nav-tabs > li.dropdown .dropdown-menu > li > a {
  color: #777;
}
.with-nav-tabs.panel-default .nav-tabs > li.dropdown .dropdown-menu > li > a:hover,
.with-nav-tabs.panel-default .nav-tabs > li.dropdown .dropdown-menu > li > a:focus {
  background-color: #ddd;
}
.with-nav-tabs.panel-default .nav-tabs > li.dropdown .dropdown-menu > .active > a,
.with-nav-tabs.panel-default .nav-tabs > li.dropdown .dropdown-menu > .active > a:hover,
.with-nav-tabs.panel-default .nav-tabs > li.dropdown .dropdown-menu > .active > a:focus {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #555;
}
.with-nav-tabs.panel-success .nav-tabs > li > a,
.with-nav-tabs.panel-success .nav-tabs > li > a:hover,
.with-nav-tabs.panel-success .nav-tabs > li > a:focus {
  color: #3c763d;
}
.with-nav-tabs.panel-success .nav-tabs > .open > a,
.with-nav-tabs.panel-success .nav-tabs > .open > a:hover,
.with-nav-tabs.panel-success .nav-tabs > .open > a:focus,
.with-nav-tabs.panel-success .nav-tabs > li > a:hover,
.with-nav-tabs.panel-success .nav-tabs > li > a:focus {
  color: #3c763d;
  background-color: #d6e9c6;
  border-color: transparent;
}
.with-nav-tabs.panel-success .nav-tabs > li.active > a,
.with-nav-tabs.panel-success .nav-tabs > li.active > a:hover,
.with-nav-tabs.panel-success .nav-tabs > li.active > a:focus {
  color: #3c763d;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-color: #d6e9c6;
  border-bottom-color: transparent;
}
.with-nav-tabs.panel-success .nav-tabs > li.dropdown .dropdown-menu {
  background-color: #dff0d8;
  border-color: #d6e9c6;
}
.with-nav-tabs.panel-success .nav-tabs > li.dropdown .dropdown-menu > li > a {
  color: #3c763d;
}
.with-nav-tabs.panel-success .nav-tabs > li.dropdown .dropdown-menu > li > a:hover,
.with-nav-tabs.panel-success .nav-tabs > li.dropdown .dropdown-menu > li > a:focus {
  background-color: #d6e9c6;
}
.with-nav-tabs.panel-success .nav-tabs > li.dropdown .dropdown-menu > .active > a,
.with-nav-tabs.panel-success .nav-tabs > li.dropdown .dropdown-menu > .active > a:hover,
.with-nav-tabs.panel-success .nav-tabs > li.dropdown .dropdown-menu > .active > a:focus {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #3c763d;
}
tbody > tr > td:first-child:before,
table.dataTable.dtr-inline.collapsed > tbody > tr > th:first-child:before {
  background-color: #5bc0de !important;
  left: 10px !important;
  top: 6px !important;
}
.modal-backdrop {
  z-index: 0 !important;
}
```

```html
<?php $_SESSION[ "page"]='Register' ; ?>
<html lang="en">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>GivingTree |
    <?php echo $_SESSION[ 'page']; ?>
  </title>

  <link href="css/datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.7/integration/bootstrap/3/dataTables.bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="//cdn.datatables.net/responsive/1.0.6/css/dataTables.responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="57x57" href="img/apple-touch-icon-57x57.png">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="60x60" href="img/apple-touch-icon-60x60.png">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" href="img/apple-touch-icon-72x72.png">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="76x76" href="img/apple-touch-icon-76x76.png">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="img/apple-touch-icon-114x114.png">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="120x120" href="img/apple-touch-icon-120x120.png">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="144x144" href="img/apple-touch-icon-144x144.png">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="152x152" href="img/apple-touch-icon-152x152.png">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="img/apple-touch-icon-180x180.png">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="img/favicon-32x32.png" sizes="32x32">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="img/android-chrome-192x192.png" sizes="192x192">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="img/favicon-96x96.png" sizes="96x96">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="img/favicon-16x16.png" sizes="16x16">
  <link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json">
  <meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#da532c">
  <meta name="msapplication-TileImage" content="img/mstile-144x144.png">
  <meta name="theme-color" content="#ffffff">


  <style type="text/css">
    .container {
      padding-bottom: 30px;
    }
    .btn-file {
      position: relative;
      overflow: hidden;
    }
    .btn-file input[type=file] {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      right: 0;
      min-width: 100%;
      min-height: 100%;
      font-size: 100px;
      text-align: right;
      filter: alpha(opacity=0);
      opacity: 0;
      background: red;
      cursor: inherit;
      display: block;
    }
    input[readonly] {
      background-color: white !important;
      cursor: text !important;
    }
  </style>

  <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
  <!-- primary: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
      <![endif]-->
</head>

<body class="blue">
  <div id="wrap" class="wrap">



    <nav class="navbar navbar-default" style="border-radius:0px;">
      <div class="container-fluid">

        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <a class="navbar-brand pull-left" href="index.php" style="padding-top:9px;">
            <img src="logo.png" width="28px" height="28px" style="float:left" />
            <div class="logo" style="float:left;color:#695b4e">GivingTree</div>
          </a>
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed visible-xs visible-sm" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#main-collapse" aria-expanded="false">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
        </div>

        <!-- Collects for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse text-center" id="main-collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="index.php?login"><span class="fa fa-sign-in"></span> Login</a>
            </li>
            <li class="active"><a href="register.php"><span class="fa fa-edit"></span> Register</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->


      </div>
      <!-- /.container-fluid -->
    </nav>

    <div class="container">

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 mtop">
          <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading text-center">
              <h4>GivingTree | <span class="text-muted">Register</span></h4>
            </div>

            <form method="post" action="register.php" name="registerform">

              <div class="panel-body">
                <div class="form-group col col-md-12">
                  <div class="loginerrors">
                    <?php // show potential errors / feedback (from registration object) if (isset($registration)) { if ($registration->errors) { foreach ($registration->errors as $error) { echo "<span class='fa fa-info-circle'> </span> "; echo $error; } } if ($registration->messages) { foreach ($registration->messages as $message) { echo $message; } } } ?>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col col-xs-12">
                  <label for="user_name">Name</label>
                  <input id="login_input_username" class="login_input form-control" type="text" pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+" name="user_name" placeholder="Name" required />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col col-xs-12">
                  <label for="user_email">Email</label>
                  <input id="login_input_email" class="login_input form-control" type="email" name="user_email" placeholder="Email" required />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col col-xs-12" id="pwd-container">
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="input group col col-sm-6">
                      <label for="password">Password</label>
                      <input name="user_password_new" type="password" class="form-control col col-sm-12" id="password" placeholder="Password" />

                      <div class="pwstrength_viewport_progress">
                        <div class="progress-bar"><span class="password-verdict"></span>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="input group col col-sm-6">
                      <label for="user_password_repeat">Repeat Password</label>

                      <input id="user_password_repeat" class="login_input form-control col col-sm-12" type="password" name="user_password_repeat" placeholder="Confirm Password" pattern=".{6,}" required autocomplete="off" />
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="panel-footer">
                <a href="index.php?login" class="btn btn-default">Logdin</a>
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" name="register" value="Register" />
              </div>

            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <?php include 'footer.php'; ?>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Do you have any custom css & do you have a jsfiddle or something I can tinker on?

Comment: It's probably something in your CSS, I just tried the code you provided and everything works fine for me.

Comment: Looks fine see fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/c9dhn9nc/29/

Comment: There is a custom css, but I havent touched it at all from when it was working. And no other page is having this issue.

Comment: @AvAvt I just added a snippet with the CSS and header for the page. The snippet doesnt have the same issue as my actual page though.

Comment: Try looking at the snippet  without your CSS and then add your CSS, then begin trimming down from your CSS to comb through what may be causing the issue

Comment: @AGE The problem with that is that my snippet with the CSS doesnt have any issues. It's just an issue with my site itself.

Comment: You mentioned that there is a custom CSS, does removing this CSS clear the issue at all? In the case that this is true, you need to understand where this custom CSS is affecting you, its probably something small that can be overcome with stricter CSS specificity on your side

Comment: @AvAvt Here is a jsfiddle for you to try if you want
https://jsfiddle.net/bzfLvmwp/2/

Comment: @AGE I got rid of the CSS completely off of my site, but the issues is still there.

Comment: Speaking in generalities: CSS wise your web inspector should literally point at what it is overriding and the source file. If it has nothing to do with CSS then perhaps is an HTML element which is in place where you did not intend it to be (a layout issue). Otherwise, your JavaScript or a backend script is causing the style change, but that can be also seen in your web inspector.... so long story short, does your web inspector show anything unusual/unintended upon inspecting your element? My best guess: it's bootstrap

Comment: Do you have any working example that contains this problem? The fiddle you provided is working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up going through all parts of code that were running in the site. Somehow, my google analytics code caused it. I'm not sure why, and why it didn't affect any other part of the website, but once I removed it, everything went back to normal. Any ideas on how why this may have happened?

Answer (score 0):

Found it in this rule inside of bootstrap.min.css:

```
.progress-bar {
    background-color: #337ab7;
    box-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15) inset;
    color: #fff;
    float: left;
    font-size: 12px;
    height: 100%;
    line-height: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    transition: width 0.6s ease 0s;
    width: 0;
}
```

That `height: 100%;` is the cause. You can fixit with:

```
.progress-bar { height: auto; }
```